# How to get Checkin Notes with Get-TFSItemHistory TFS Powershell command

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfs-power-tools

I am trying to use TFS PowerShell command line utility for getting changeset details after a certain date. 
I need the Check-in notes fields specifically `CodeReviewer`. I am able to get other fields correctly. But `CodeReviewer` is always blank. I have not accessed it correctly in this command. :(

Any pointers would be really helpful!

```
$tfsServerString = "server string"
$tfs = Get-TfsServer $tfsServerString
Get-TfsItemHistory $/folderPath -Server $tfs -Version "D15/04/13~" -includeitems `
        -Recurse  | 
    Select CreationDate, ChangeSetId, Committer, CodeReviewer, Comment `
        -exp WorkItems |
    Format-Table  CreationDate, ChangeSetId, Committer,CodeReviewer, `
        @{n='WorkId'; e={$_.Id}} , Comment -Wrap >
    C:\Status\WithID.txt
```

Comment: Look at the "Fields" property, in this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463800/how-to-access-custom-or-non-system-tfs-workitem-fields-using-powershell